# Trouble reading hex from one file and writing to another

Tags: c#, hex

I have a .dat file with some stuff in it. I want to read a portion of the hex in it, and then write it to a new file. Here's what my file looks like in a hex editor:
[image: Original file]

Here's what my new file looks like:
[image: New file]

If you look at the first line of my first file, over on the left it reads
Do041220B. On my new file, the first line reads D.o.0.4.1.2.2.0.B
For some reason, it's putting 00 between everything.

Here's my code:

```
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();            
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        int happyint=0x0;
        int angryint = 0x1;
        switch (textBox1.Text)
        {

            case "1":
                happyint = 0x0;
                angryint = 0x610;
                break;
            case "2":
                happyint = 0x620;
                angryint = 0xC30;
                break;
            case "3":
                happyint = 0xC40;
                angryint = 0x1250;
                break;
            default:
                return;
                break;
        }

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(Application.StartupPath + "/" + textBox1.Text + "file.dat"));
        bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x0;
        for (int i = happyint; i <= angryint; i++)
        {
            br.BaseStream.Position = i;
            bw.Write(br.ReadByte());
            bw.BaseStream.Position += 0x1;
        }
        bw.Close();
        br.Close();
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the loop? (Ignore what you're seeing on the right side in your hex editor, and look at the actual hex values on the left side. Compare each one of the first four hex values (`44 6F 30 34` in the top image). What's different about the same four values in the bottom image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are manually advancing the position in the stream

```
// this is wrong!!
bw.BaseStream.Position += 0x1;
```

This is unnecessary, as [`BinaryWriter.Write(Byte)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tky7ax3(v=vs.110).aspx)
will write the byte *and advance the stream position itself*.

Manually incrementing the `Position`, after this write, causes the position to move beyond the current length of the file, and the intervening gap (of 1 byte), is filled with a zero.

On a similar note, `BinaryReader` also advances the stream position after `ReadByte`.  There is no need to be resetting that position on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code automatically advances the stream position by one byte on completion:

```
bw.Write(br.ReadByte());
```

When you then increment manually:

```
bw.BaseStream.Position += 0x1;
```

you are adding the extra zero byte value.